# Windows 10 1803 reboot after screen lock

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates, lenovo-laptop

I need help with Windows 10 1803 build. 
Laptop where the Windows is running is Lenovo t480s.
This laptop restart in random moments without blue screen during lock.

It cannot be releated to Windows update because for testing purpose Windows Update Service has been disabled.

MemTest was running result : no issue with ram

SSD is at good health.
All Hardware looks good.

I may be some driver but here also drivers all update, BIOS also.

No minidump.

Example scenario: User going at cafe, lock laptop, back after 10 minutes and laptop is rebooted.

At internet is many threads about Windows update but it is completely block.

Maybe someone of You saw similar problem and may help me.

EDIT:

I found 5 blue screen IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL ntoskrnl.exe it persist in 3-4 days interval.

EDIT2:

Log information:

```
Probably caused by : partmgr.sys ( partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower+13c )

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower+13c
fffff809`d6a536ac 4c8b6c2470      mov     r13,qword ptr [rsp+70h]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  246c8b4c

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower+13c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: partmgr

IMAGE_NAME:  partmgr.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5fff5c01

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17134.228

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  13c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower

BUCKET_ID:  AV_partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  AV_partmgr!PmUpdateIoPower
```

What it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the lock screen function to see if the issue still exists.

In most cases, you will experience partmgr.sys blue screen errors after you’ve installed new hardware or software. These partmgr.sys blue screens can appear during program installation, while a partmgr.sys-related software program (eg. Windows Codename WhistlerProfessional Checked/Debug Build) is running, while a Microsoft driver is being loaded, or during Windows startup or shutdown. Keeping track of when and where your STOP error occurs is a critical piece of information in troubleshooting the problem.

Causes of Partmgr.sys Errors

Partmgr.sys blue screen errors can be caused by a variety of hardware, firmware, driver, or software issues. These could be related to either Windows Codename WhistlerProfessional Checked/Debug Build software or Microsoft hardware, but it is not necessarily the case.

More specifically, these partmgr.sys errors can be caused by:

Incorrectly configured, old, or corrupted Windows Codename WhistlerProfessional 
Checked/Debug Build device drivers. (very common)

Corruption in Windows registry from a recent partmgr.sys-related software change (install or uninstall).

Virus or malware infection that has corrupted the partmgr.sys file or related Windows 
Codename WhistlerProfessional Checked/Debug Build program files.

Hardware conflict after installing new Microsoft hardware, or hardware related to partmgr.sys.

Damaged or removed system files after you’ve installed software or drivers related to Windows Codename WhistlerProfessional Checked/Debug Build.

partmgr.sys blue screen caused by a damaged hard disk.

partmgr.sys STOP error due to memory (RAM) corruption.

Source:
How To Fix Partmgr.sys Blue Screen Errors (BSOD)

https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/bsod-blue-screen-error/sys/windows/microsoft/windows-codename-whistlerprofessional-checked-debug-build/partmgr-sys/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think i resolve problem after analyze this logs deeply i found problem with outdated software to mail encryption. Upgrade this program with including drivers resolved problem at this moment. Was not compatible with Windows 10 1803.